# Make HTTP Request With Chef to Openshift API

Tags: ssl, chef-infra, openshift

I am trying to make an API request to my local Minishift cluster to create a project request using chef.

```
http_request 'create_project_request' do
  action :post     
  url 'https://192.168.99.104:8443/apis/project.openshift.io/v1/projectrequests'
  message({
    "kind": "ProjectRequest",
    "apiVersion": "project.openshift.io/v1",
    "description": "A test project request made with Chef",
    "displayName": "Test",
    "metadata": {
      "name": "test-project"
    }
    }.to_json)
  headers({
    "AUTHORIZATION" => "Bearer $token",
    "Content-Type" => "application/json"
    })
   end
```

When I run the recipe, I get an error that says the SSL certificate verify failed.

I've been trying to use the openssl client to try and manually download the certificate and add it to /etc/chef/trusted_certs, however the openssl client does not allow you to download a certificate without a hostname.

Is there anyway to get around the SSL verification, or to get chef to accept HTTP requests to servers with self signed certificates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `openssl s_client -connect 192.168.99.104:8443 -debug -showcerts` to get the certificate data. Then put it in a file in `trusted_certs/`.